# asp.net Html.CheckBoxListFor, Position doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, checkboxlist

i'm trying to use Position.Vertical to make my checkboxlist vertical, but keep getting the error "the name "Position" doesn't exist in current context"

```
 @Html.CheckBoxListFor(modelItem => item.Value.postedItems.IDs,
                      modelItem => item.Value.availItems,
                      i => i.Id,
                      i => i.Name,
                      modelItem => item.Value.selectedItems,                        
                      Position.Vertical)
```

If i go to definition of Html.checkboxlistfor there is override for parameter Position, but for some reasons it isn't used.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty, TItem, TValue, TKey>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> listNameExpr, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> sourceDataExpr, Expression<Func<TItem, TValue>> valueExpr, Expression<Func<TItem, TKey>> textToDisplayExpr, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> selectedValuesExpr, HtmlListInfo wrapInfo);



public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty, TItem, TValue, TKey>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> listNameExpr, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> sourceDataExpr, Expression<Func<TItem, TValue>> valueExpr, Expression<Func<TItem, TKey>> textToDisplayExpr, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> selectedValuesExpr, Position position);
```

First override is used instead of second. Is there some way to force to use second case?

Comment: You need to add your Position class Namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you did not declare the right "using" reference.
Try adding `@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model` to your view.